# How to get all checked rows when using checkcolumn config

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch

If we are using selModel config then its easy to retrieve all the checked rows as follows.

```
selModel: Ext.create('Ext.selection.CheckboxModel', {
                    checkOnly: true
                })
```

we can retrieve all the checked rows using following

```
grid.getSelectionModel().getSelection();
```

But if i dont give selection Model, rather i use checkcolumn as one of the grid column as follows

```
columns: [{
xtype: 'checkcolumn',
    width: 90,
    dataIndex: 'selection',
    //stopSelection: false 
}]
```

how to retrive all the checked columns from grid in above case.

The Ext.grid.column.Check provides **checkchange** event but what if i want to collect all the checked rows and do some operation like delete.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

you could do it this way:

```
grid.getStore().each(function(record){
    if(record.get('seletion') === true){
        store.remove(record);
    }
});
```